# Querying registry for windows edition and being returned wrong value

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I recently tried querying registry for the windows edition and was returned the wrong value. I attempted this on my own pc and was returned "Windows 10 Enterprise" even though the reg value is "Window 10 pro". I'm a little confused on why it's returning this value.

```
QueryReg(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", "ProductName", windowsEdition);
```

Comment: What does RegEdit say?

Comment: What is the `ProductName` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`? If it's "*enterprise*" then you are writing 32b code and getting [redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector).

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. It's working perfectly in x64.